# Crawling case-sensitive URLs but Scraping case-insensitive with Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, case-sensitive

I am using Scrapy to crawl and scrape numerous websites. Scrapy needs to crawl the URLs in a case-sensitive mode as this is an important information when requesting a web page. Many websites link to some of the webpages using different casings of the same URLs which fools Scrapy into creating duplicates scrapes.

For example, the page https://www.example.com/index.html links to https://www.example.com/User1.php and https://www.example.com/user1.php

We need Scrapy to collect both pages as when we see the page User1.php, we do not know yet that we will collect a clone of it later through user1.php. We cannot lowercase https://www.example.com/User1.php either during the crawl as the server may return a 404 error when the page https://www.example.com/user1.php is not available.

So what I am looking for is a solution to tell Scrapy to crawl URLs in a case-sensitive mode, but to duplicate filter the pages, once collected, in a case-insensitive mode before they are scraped to eliminate the risks of duplicates.

Does anyone know how to operate Scrapy under both modes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to create a custom `DupeFilter` that [extends `BaseDupeFilter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.7.3/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L8), then set [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "my_package.MyDupeFilter"`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.7/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) in your `settings.py`

You may have plenty of luck just subclassing the existing `RFPDupeFilter` and inserting a line into [`def request_seen(self, request)`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.7.3/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L46) that case-folds the URL before fingerprinting it:

```py
class MyDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def request_seen(self, request):
        lc_req = request.replace(url=request.url.lower())
        return super(MyDupeFilter, self).request_seen(lc_req)
```

In fact, that sounds like such a common feature, if you find that change works for you, then submit a PR to Scrapy to add [`case_fold = settings.getbool("DUPEFILTER_CASE_INSENSITIVE")`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.7.3/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L43) so others can benefit from that change